# Apache Mahout Advices?

Tags: recommendation-engine, mahout

Have you implemented Apache Mahout recommendation engine? any advices you can share? any other sites you know that use Mahout?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You will get the best information about Mahout on the Mahout user mailing lists:

http://mahout.apache.org/mailinglists.html

Comment: +1 like Ted says, posting about what you're trying to do on that list should get you a lot of pointers to how to think about it. Mahout isn't one thing but a framework and collection of processes, so, advice will go a long way to making the right sense of it. I know of several private projects using it, one big news site which can't be named, and I know Mippin uses it too.

Answer (score 0):

The most useful brief, single page for me was the [Mahout First-Timer FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/recommender-first-timer-faq.html). Based on what was written there, I decided to start with a non-distributed recommender instead of leaping into one of the Hadoop-based ones.

I also recommend the book Mahout in Action, which helped me a lot. Whether it's worth buying or not is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510471/is-it-worth-purchasing-mahout-in-action-to-get-up-to-speed-with-mahout-or-are-t), but it seems to get pretty positive reviews from most people (which I agree with).